# Quartiles of an Ungrouped Data causing me confusion

Tags: statistics

The example on this worksheet which shows how to find the quartiles of an Ungrouped data made me confused as to why they would round up at 2.5 but not at 7.5 and as to why they should round up at all instead of finding the average of "3 and 4" and "9 and 14" or am I just missing something here.

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJw47.jpg)

Additional info:

Here's my situation right now: I chose the option of "Instead of having an online class, our school hands out these Self-Learning Worksheets to make us learn by ourselves." As a matter of fact, we do have online classes. But it isn't mandatory to join it. They call it "supplementing our Worksheets". I didn't join the class because I thought to myself that I can just look up those lessons in the internet i.e. YouTube. Which I had success in. Having a second opinion/source really helped me in these times but this is the only time where the two seems to not correlate with each other.

Comment: You have the nine numbers $1,3,4,5,5,6,9,14,21$.  Clearly the median is $5$.  The first and third quartiles depend on precisely what definition you are using and how many terms you have.  Their approach is not what I would use, thought their answers of $4$ and $9$ are what I would say here.  But you need to learn the definition likely to be used in any exam

Comment: Thank you, would you mind sharing how you would approach this? considering that you have the same answer as theirs?

Comment: For me the $4$ represents from $\frac29$ to $\frac39$ of  the ordered data and $\frac14$ is inside this range.  Similarly  $5$   represents from $\frac39$ to $\frac59$ of  the ordered data and $\frac12$ is inside this range, while $9$   represents from $\frac69$ to $\frac79$ of  the ordered data and $\frac34$ is inside this range.

Comment: I still can't seem to understand it sorry, but thanks for your answer nonetheless. I only noticed that Q1 has 1 element to the left until it reaches the minimum value and also 1 element to the right before it reaches the median. Same as Q3 which has 1 element to the right the reach the maximum and 1 element to the left to reach the median. Do you think this plays a factor on determining the Q1 and Q3?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no standard definition for quantiles.**
Rules for finding them vary among textbooks and software programs.

In R statistical software one can use the default method, or choose from about 10 frequently used alternative methods.

Differences among methods can give surprisingly different answers for small datasets, but for
large datasets (where quantiles are most often
used in statistical practice) differences among methods are not so important.

While in your current statistics course, make sure you understand the method to be used and use it consistently throughout. (Do not expect software or a statistical calculator to give the same answers as the method of your textbook.)

Below is a fictitious dataset of size $n=10$ sampled from a
Poisson distribution, using R. A few different
types of quantile rules are used to find min, lower quartile, median, upper quartile, and max.

Because 10 is not divisible by 4 and because
there are ties in the data, compromises may be required in order to compute the quartiles and median; different types make different compromises.

```
set.seed(2021) # for reproducibility 
x = rpois(10, 3);  sort(x)
 [1] 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 7

quantile(x)  # R default type=7
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 2.0  3.0  3.5  4.0  7.0 
quantile(x, type=1)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   2    3    3    4    7 
quantile(x, type=3)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   2    2    3    4    7 
quantile(x, type=4)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 2.0  2.5  3.0  4.0  7.0
```